# Access 2016 VBA works for Double Click but not click Events

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access, events

I have a "close" button on an Access 2016 form to close the form.  I started out with a Click event and it doesn't work unless I click it a second time.

So I added a double click event (same code) and it works flawlessly.  I would prefer to use a single click event since every other button on the form works with a single click.

The only reason for adding the double click event was because the click event wasn't working like I expected it to.

I put a break point in the first line of the Click event to see if any other code (modules) were run and there wasn't any.  When I put the break point in and step through the code it works with a single click.

The code below for both events is identical.  Any suggestions of advice would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance for the help.....

fyi.........The DoEvents and On Error GoTo 0 were added after doing some research and trying these suggestions to track / resolve the issue....

```
Private Sub btn_CloseForm_Click()      
    DoEvents
    On Error GoTo 0

    DoCmd.SetWarnings False
    
    DoCmd.Close acForm, "frm_Dashboard", acSaveNo
    
    DoCmd.SetWarnings True
    
End Sub

Private Sub btn_CloseForm_DblClick(Cancel As Integer)

    DoEvents
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    DoCmd.SetWarnings False
    
    DoCmd.Close acForm, "frm_Dashboard", acSaveNo
    
    DoCmd.SetWarnings True

End Sub
```

Thanks again for taking the time to look at my issue.......

Comment: Remove all code lines except for `DoCmd.Close acForm, "frm_Dashboard", acSaveNo` and see if it works.

Comment: @Toni............Thanks...........I figured it out.  I was closing a payments form to return to the dashboard.  Before it opened the Dashboard, it was refreshing it.  Then when the dashboard was opened, it also refreshes it.  So 2 refreshes.  I took the refresh out when closing the payment form and it works like I expected.

I think it worked when I stepped through it because both refreshes wer done and it didn't work on the single click event because it was doing the refresh a second time.

Developer error (again!)  Thanks for the suggestion...